# Can't access redis docker volume

Tags: macos, docker, redis

I can't access redis volume:

```
   docker run --name redis --volume=data:/data/:rw -p 6379:6379 -d redis

    b60c15a0a3e05d7cdb383415192927b4fc1563be5350924a01fe70f6a29ab113

    ls: data/: No such file or directory
```

Why? Doesn't docker create a host volume by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **named volumes** or **bind volumes**, but don't use dot `.` for relative path.

## docker run

### bind volumes

You have to use absolute path:

```
docker run --name redis --mount type=bind,source="/<absolutepath>/data",target=/app -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```

### named volumes

You cannot use '.' for docker volume name.

```
docker run --name redis --volume=data:/data/:rw -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```

After this command, a named volume is generated: you can check it doing:

```
docker volume ls | grep data
```

## docker-compose

With docker compose, you can define

```
services:
  your-redis-service:
  ...
  volumes:
    - ./data:/data
```

In this case, docker-compose translate relative path to your working directory to absolute path for bind volumes.

Comment: Thank you! `docker run --name redis --mount type=bind,source="/Users/igracheva/IdeaProjects/smart-hub/local-stack/data_redis/data",target=/data -p 6379:6379 -d redis` worked for me, I can't make docker to write something there. I run redis-cli, set key, however I can't see anithing in the folder